# Contravariant powerset functor and cartesian closedness

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, adjoint-functors, functors

$\newcommand{\POWER}[1]{\mathcal{P}(#1)}
\newcommand{\FS}{\rightarrow}
\newcommand{\CCC}{\mathsf{C}}
$**Background.** I'm interested in the relationship between two basic and well-known categorical constructs, the contravariant powerset functor, and cartesian closedness. Both are ubiquitous and in particular, the category of sets and functions has both.
I think that the  question below must have been resolved a long time ago,
  but I could not find anything online and in the books I consulted.

Recall that  the contravariant powerset functor $\POWER{\cdot}$ maps sets to their powersets, and functions $f: A \FS B$ to $\POWER{f} : \POWER{B} \FS
\POWER{A}$ to their 'inverses' like this: $S \mapsto \{a \in A\ |\ fa \in S\}$.

A category $\CCC$ is cartesian closed if any finite family of
  objects has a product in $\CCC$, and any two objects $A$ and $B$
  from $\CCC$ have an exponential object $B^A$ in $\CCC$.  In
  particular (and simplifying a bit), there is an natural family of evaluation
  morphisms $ev_{ABC}$ from $A \FS (B \FS C)$ to $(A \times B) \FS C$ that is
  iso.

**Question.** What is known about the combination
of cartesian-closed structure and the contravariant powerset functor? Do they go well
together with each other or not? In particular, how to $\POWER{\cdot}$
  and $ev$ relate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $\mathbf{Set}$, we have the standard result that $\mathcal{P}X\cong\mathbf{2}^X$ where $\mathbf{2}\cong\{0,1\}$. This generalizes to any elementary [topos](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topos) where $\mathbf{2}$ is replaced by $\Omega$, the subobject classifier (which is $\mathbf{2}$ in $\mathbf{Set}$). An elementary topos can be defined as a finitely complete category with [power objects](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/power+object). We can then show that $\mathcal{P}1$, the power object of the terminal object, is a subobject classifier, i.e. $\Omega$, and then we can show that $\mathcal{P}X\cong\Omega^X$ in general. We can further show that the category is cartesian closed, roughly by mimicking the set-theoretic definition of functions as graphs.

Deriving all this (and much more) from the definition of elementary topos is a very good exercise, and is covered in any introduction to topos theory.

Comment: Thanks. That's roughly what I know, but how does that work for more complicated objects? Let's say I have a morphism $(A
\rightarrow B) \rightarrow (C \rightarrow D)$ and I want to 'invert'
it using the contravariant powerset functor, and then I want to
minimise the number of function-space constructors, replacing them by
products, i.e. I want to uncurry the result as much as possible. That
means roughly that I need to commute contravariant powerset functor
and evaluation. How is this done?

Comment: I assume by "invert it" you mean produce a morphism $D^C\to\mathcal{P}(B^A)$. Calling the original morphism $f$, this is just $\mathcal{P}f\circ\{-\}_{D^C}$ where $\{-\}_X:X\to\mathcal{P}X$ is the singleton map, i.e. $\mathsf{curry}(=_X)$ where $=_X:X\times X\to\Omega$. Then you just uncurry it if you want: $\mathsf{uncurry}(\mathcal{P}f\circ\{-\}_{D^C})$. You don't need to "commute" anything until you try to establish an equality, and even then there's no difference between $\mathcal{P}$ and any other exponential. $\Omega$ is special though. I don't understand what you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful as my mind is in knots about this.  Why  do
use $D^C \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(B^A)$ and
not $C^D \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(B^A)$? The latter is what you get when you
'thread through' the contravariant powerset functor.